# One Itemize problem

Tags: itemize

Good morning.

I want to have the bold texts on the left side next to left margin. But my result is the picture below.

Thanks for help.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
%46paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=slovak,english]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
%showframe
\usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[sfdefault,thin]{roboto}
\usepackage{ amssymb }

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\textbf{abrupt}}]       \quad {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont [\textipa{@\textprimstress br2pt}]}\\
    {náhly, neočakávaný $\blacklozenge$ strohý, úsečný}
  \item[{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\textbf{acidic}}]       \quad {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont [\textipa{@\textprimstress sId.Ik}]}\\
{kyslý, kyselinový}
  \item[{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\textbf{adorable}}]     \quad {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont [\textipa{@\textprimstress dO:.r@.b\super@l}]}\\  
    {rozkošný, nádherný}
  \item[{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\textbf{adventurous}}]  \quad {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont [\textipa{@d\textprimstress ven.tS\super @r.@s}]}\\   
    {odvážny, smelý \textit{(ochotný riskovať ap.)} $\blacklozenge$ dobrodružný}
\end{itemize}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look into the suggestions to your previous question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338605/36296

Comment: Maybe start from a [Dictionary Template from latextemplates.com](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/dictionary)?

Comment: I did it in `itemize` but I forgot how.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Who helps me.   I need help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have noticed the label in `\item` only occupy a space large enough for the bullet. If you have longer it will run out in the left margin, and eventually out of the page. In your case it is more convenient to use a `tabular`, or as in the example below `tabularx`. A simplified version of your example can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
%%% Test of long item label
\begin{itemize}
\item[Test of long label] sdjkgf
\item  jsdgfjbc
\end{itemize}

Tabular:

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX}
  \textbf{abrupt}      & {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont [text]}\\
  & náhly, neocakávaný strohý, úsečný \\
  \textbf{acidic}      & {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont [text]}\\
  & kyslý, kyselinový \\
  \textbf{adorable}    & {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont [text]}\\  
  & rozkošný, nádherný \\
  \textbf{adventurous} & {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont [text]}\\   
  & odvážny, smelý \textit{(ochotný riskovať ap.)} dobrodružný 
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

use the environment `description`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
%46paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=slovak,english]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{calc}
%showframe
\usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, 
bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
%\usepackage[sfdefault,thin]{roboto}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\newcommand\qag[1]{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont 
\makebox[\widthof{adventurous}][r]{#1}}
\newcommand\phv[2][]{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
     [\textipa{#1@\textprimstress#2}]}}

\begin{document}

\hrule

\begin{description}
\item[\qag{abrupt}]  \quad \phv{br2pt}\\
        náhly, neočakávaný $\blacklozenge$ strohý, úsečný
\item[\qag{acidic}]  \quad \phv{sId.Ik}\\
        kyslý, kyselinový
\item[\qag{adorable}]\quad \phv{dO:.r@.b\super@l}\\  
        rozkošný, nádherný
\item[\qag{adventurous}]\quad \phv[d]{ven.tS\super @r.@s}\\   
        odvážny, smelý \textit{(ochotný riskovať ap.)} $\blacklozenge$ dobrodružný
\end{description}  

\end{document}
```

[image]